# What are the functional differences in these 3 pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm relatively new to pytest-style unit testing, and I'm trying to learn more about pytest fixtures.  I'm not passing a scope argument to the fixture, so I know that the scope is "function".  Are there any functional differences in these 3 styles of simple fixtures?  Why would one approach be favored over the others?

```
@pytest.fixture()
@patch('a.b.c.structlog.get_logger')
def fixture_classQ(mock_log):
    handler = MagicMock(spec=WidgetHandler)
    return ClassQ(handler)
```

```
@pytest.fixture()
def fixture_classQ():
    with patch('a.b.c.structlog.get_logger'):
        handler = MagicMock(spec=WidgetHandler)
        return ClassQ(handler)
```

```
@pytest.yield_fixture()
def fixture_classQ():
    with patch('a.b.c.structlog.get_logger'):
        handler = MagicMock(spec=WidgetHandler)
        yield ClassQ(handler)
```

Simple example usage of the fixture:

```
def test_classQ_str(fixture_classQ):
    assert str(fixture_classQ) == "This is ClassQ"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### fixture 1

Starting with the first one, this creates a plain-data fixture.  The mock is (imo misleadingly) only alive for the duration of the fixture function because it uses `return`.

In order ~roughly what happens for that:

- pytest notices your fixture is used for the test function
- it calls the fixture function

  - the mock decorator starts the patch
  - the mock decorator calls your actual function (which returns a value)
  - the mock decorator undoes the patch
- pytest notices it wasn't a generator and so that's the value of your fixture

#### fixture 2

the second is identical in behaviour to the first, except it uses the context manager form of `mock` instead of the decorator.  personally I don't like the decorator form but that's just me :D

#### fixture 3

*(first before I continue, `pytest.yield_fixture` is a deprecated alias for `pytest.fixture` -- you can just use `@pytest.fixture`)*

The third does something different!  The patch is alive for the duration of the test because it has "yielded" during the fixture.  This is a kind of way to create a setup + teardown fixture all in one.  Here's roughly the execution here

- pytest notices your fixture is used for the test function
- pytest calls the fixture function

  - since it is a generator, it returns immediately without executing code
- pytest notices it is a generator, calls `next(...)` on it

  - this causes the code to execute until the `yield` and then "pausing".  you can think of it kind of as a co-routine
  - the `__enter__` of the `mock` is called making the patch active
  - the value that is `yield`ed is used as the value of the fixture
- pytest then executes your test function
- pytest then calls `next(...)` again on the generator to exhaust the fixture

  - this `__exit__`s the with statement, undoing the patch

#### which to choose?

the best answer is *it depends*.  Since 1 and 2 are functionally equivalent it's up to personal preference.  Pick 3. if you need the patch to be active during the entire duration of your test.  And don't use `pytest.yield_fixture`, just use `pytest.fixture`.

Comment: Excellent response, thank you.  Could I get you to edit your answer and use "fixture function" and "test function" everywhere you used "function"?  This would help clarify and ensure that I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: This is the best explanation of how fixtures work! Now I understand why my tests break when I use return instead of yield.