# Why are the values yielded by a pytest fixture and a function called directly different?

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

In the code below, what I get is a generator object

```
<generator object a at 0x7feb40b2d7b0>
```

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def get_playwright():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright

print(get_playwright())
```

But when I use pytest, what I get is a class object

```
<class 'playwright.sync_api._generated.Playwright'>`:
```

```
# conftest.py

import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

@pytest.fixture()
def get_playwright():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright
```

```
# test_one.py

def test(get_playwright):
    print(get_playwright)
```

I wonder why this is happening? How to get class without using pytest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st form:

```
def get_playwright():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright

print(get_playwright())  # <generator object get_playwright at 0x108aac580>
```

That is expected because `get_playwright` is a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), which returns a [generator iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator), which you have to call [`next(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on to get each yielded value from the iterator.

Consider a simpler, non-playwright example:

```
In [14]: def generate_nums():
    ...:     for num in range(10):
    ...:         yield num
    ...: 

In [15]: nums = generate_nums()

In [16]: nums
Out[16]: <generator object generate_nums at 0x11115e6d0>

In [17]: next(nums)
Out[17]: 0

In [18]: next(nums)
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: next(nums)
Out[19]: 2
```

For more examples, see [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/2745495).

Since your `get_playwright` returns an iterator, you need to call `next()` *once* to get the actual object:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright


def get_playwright():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright

playwright_generator = get_playwright()
print(playwright_generator)  # <generator object get_playwright at 0x104031580>

playwright = next(playwright_generator)
print(playwright)  # <playwright._impl._playwright.Playwright object at 0x1041aabb0>
```

---

For the 2nd form:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def get_playwright():
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        yield playwright

def test(get_playwright):
    print(get_playwright)
```

It should be the same case, *but* it's just that pytest automatically calls `next()` on the fixture value if it's a generator. I could not find documentation for this behavior from the pytest docs, but it was mentioned by one of the pytest author's/maintainer's [in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303406/2745495):

> Here's roughly the execution here
>
> - pytest notices your fixture is used for the test function
> - **pytest calls the fixture function**
>
>   - **since it is a generator, it returns immediately without executing code**
> - **pytest notices it is a generator, calls `next(...)` on it**
>
>   - **this causes the code to execute until the `yield` and then "pausing".**  you can think of it kind of as a co-routine
>     ...
> - pytest then executes your test function

...which is probably why the value passed to your test function is already the `next`-ed value, the playwright object.