# pytest-html extras customizing code understanding

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html, pytest-html-reporter

I'm trying to customize report.html of pytest using pytest-html plugin.

I searched up many sites(including pytest-html documentation) and found that the code below is commonly used.(The code is in conftest.py)

(https://pytest-html.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#extra-content)

```py
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper = True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.outcome == "call":
        #always add url to report
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("http://www.google.com/"))
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.text('Hi', name = 'TEXT'))
            # only add additional html on failure
            # extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html("<div>Additional HTML</div>"))
        report.extra = extra
```

However, I have no idea of each lines.

No one explained what the line does actually.

Why does the script allocates **yield** keyword to outcome with out any variable(e.g. yield 1), and what does yield.get_result() actually do?

Also, I have no idea of xfail("wasxfail").

I found that @pytest.xfail makes the test function fail in the pytest run, but I think it has nothing to do with the above code.

Why don't we use 'fail' not 'xfail'?

Anyway, what I need is

**First**, the meaning of each line and what it does.

**Second**, I wanna set different message in the report.html depending on the pass/fail.

I tried `python report.outcome == 'failed', report.outcome == 'passed'` to divide conditions, but it didn't work.

**Third**, when adding the text not url, it becomes  tag and helps redirecting the page containing the text.

However, if I click the page in the html, it opens **about:blank** page not the desired one.

Using right click and open in new tab redirects to the desired one.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

---

+ I have more questions, I tried

```py
if report.passed:
    extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("https://www.google.com/")
report.extra = extra
```

It attaches 3 same links in the report.html(Results table) How can I handle it?

+ I could log a message when test is failed like `msg = 'hi', pytest.fail(msg)` However, I cannot get a clue to do it when the test is passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to answer as many lines as possible.

Pytest uses [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72027987/why-are-the-values-yielded-by-a-pytest-fixture-and-a-function-called-directly-di) to iterate over the report steps.

The function `pytest_runtest_makereport` iterates over every `result.when` (not .outcome, this is a bug in the documentation) which according to pytest are as [follows](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/310b67b2271cb05f575054c1cdd2ece2412c89a2/src/_pytest/runner.py#L283): 'collect', 'setup', 'call', and 'teardown'.

The `get_result` is how [pytest](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/doc/en/how-to/writing_hook_functions.rst#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks) implements its hooks.

The confusion about `failed` and `xfail` (expected to fail) is how you define a test failure: It is an error if it was skipped but was expected to fail or if it failed but was not expected to fail.

The thing with the **about:blank** could also be a [bug](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/issues).

What you want to use your if statements on is not the call info but the [report](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/reports.py#L146):

```
if report.failed:
    do_stuff()
if report.passed:
    do_stuff_different()
```

One way to get more info about code and its context would be to debug it using `breakpoint()`.

So the snippet you are looking for is:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == "call":
        xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("http://www.google.com/"))
        if report.passed:
            extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("http://www.stackoverflow.com/"))
        report.extra = extra
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have more questions, I tried ```if report.passed: extra.append(pytest_html.extras.url("https://www.google.com/") report.extra = extra```, and it attaches 3 same links in the report.html(Results table) How can I handle it?

+ I could log a message when test is failed like msg = 'hi', pytest.fail(msg)

However, I cannot get a clue to do it when the test is passed.

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to extend questions in comments, how about you update your question?

Comment: I also think you're right. I edited the question!

Comment: @jaemmin I updated my answer. The snippet should do what you are looking for.

Comment: I was having a hard time for a couple of weeks dealing with pytest, pytest-html. Reading documentations, stacks, and with your help I came up with a good result. Thank you for you kind answer.